# MongoDB search unknown value of 2 fields

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I am new to `pymongo` and was wondering how I pull 2 fields with unknown values?

sample data:

```
{ _id: "fisher-price-baby-bath-tubs", 
  cwc: "<div id = 'cwcBlock'><b>Fisher-Price Bath Tubs</b><p><div>",
  pov: null 
}
{ _id: "go-camping-gadgets", 
  cwc: "<a href=\"http://commerce.com/inspire/greatoutdoors\", 
  title="\" alt=\"Great Outdoors\"\"></a>" 
}
```

I want to pull `_id` & `cwc`.

Currently I'm using `collection.distinct('_id')` & `collection.distinct('cwc')` to pull each field individually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the combination of distinct `_id` and `cwc`, you could use the aggregation pipeline as below:

```
 db.collection.aggregate([
 {$group:{"_id":{"_id":"$id","cwc":"$cwc"},"id":{$first:"$_id"},"cwc":{$first:"$cwc"}}},
 {$project:{"_id":0,"id":1,"cwc":1}}
 ])
```

If duplicates are acceptable:

```
 db.collection.find({},{"cwc":1});
```

would do.

Comment: Thank you so much, how would I do a find, if only if the _id contains a cwc?

Comment: I tried `collection.find({},{"cwc":{"$exists": True}})` but I get a `Unsupported projection option: $exists`

Comment: You cannot check for existence condition in the projection part. try, `db.collection.find({"cwc":{$exists:true}})`.